# Check Comma Seperated Values in field PHP mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a field in a table named filters and it can have comma seperated values 1,2,3 or 3,1 or more.I need to select only those records which matches these records in field.Suppose someone send 1,3 and it must exists in filters field ie **and** operation.

I am using FIND_IN_SET and it is working fine for single value,suppose someone sends 1 and it is getting correct records but if someone send comma seperated 1,3 then it is giving following error

> Invalid query: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native
>   function 'FIND_IN_SET'

For single record i am using following query and it is working fine.

```
SELECT shoptitle,
        logopic,
        complocality, 
        profileurl, 
        lat, 
        lng,
        mageuserid,
        compdesi,
        deliverymin,
        deleiveryprice,
        deleiverymethod,
        vendorphone,
        compcity,
        compstate,
        zipcode,
        showcompleteaddress,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('33.8352932') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-117.91450359999999') ) + sin( radians('33.8352932') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM userdata 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET (1,filter) 
HAVING distance < '10'   
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: normalize your database, create a separate table for these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to normalise you database, removing the comma separated list of value. The problem with these is that it is difficult to check multiple values (as you are finding), but even for a single value any check will not use an index so will be slow.

Failing that you need to split up you list to check, and then use FIND_IN_SET on each one to check it is in the field.

Something like this:-

```
$some_values = "1,3";

$some_values_array = explode(',', $some_values);

$Some_checks = "FIND_IN_SET ('".implode("',filter) AND FIND_IN_SET ('", $some_values_array).")";

$sql = "SELECT shoptitle,
            logopic,
            complocality, 
            profileurl, 
            lat, 
            lng,
            mageuserid,
            compdesi,
            deliverymin,
            deleiveryprice,
            deleiverymethod,
            vendorphone,
            compcity,
            compstate,
            zipcode,
            showcompleteaddress,
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('33.8352932') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-117.91450359999999') ) + sin( radians('33.8352932') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM userdata 
    WHERE $Some_checks
    HAVING distance < '10'   
    ORDER BY distance";
```

Strictly speaking it is possible to do this in SQL, but it would be quite horrible and difficult to maintain, while also being slower.

Answer (score 0):

**you must have to check that string contain comma or not by using below code**

```
sqlvalue="1,2,3,4";
   $HiddenProducts = explode(',',$sqlvalue);
if (in_array(1, $HiddenProducts)) {
  echo "Available";
}
if (in_array(3, $HiddenProducts)) {
  echo "available";
}
```

Comment: suppose if it has comma like 1,3 and we need to find only records which have filters fields value 1,3 or 1,2,3,4,5 ie 1,3 must exists in that field. how to do this?

Comment: that means you dont want value other than 1,3

Comment: no,we only need those records which have 1,3 in filters fields suppose **A has 1,2,3,4,5 and B has 4,5,3** then it should return us A because in B we dont have 3.

Comment: thanks for editing your answer,but you didn't understand what i need exactly

Answer (score 0):

> in my case i did the following solution:

```
        $filter = '1,2,3,4,5';
        $newbreak = explode(",",$filter);
        $checksize  = sizeof($newbreak);

        if ($checksize == 2)
        {
            $new = "FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[0].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[1].",filter)";
        }elseif($checksize == 3)
        {
            $new = "FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[0].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[1].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[2].",filter)";
        }
        elseif($checksize == 4)
        {
            $new = "FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[0].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[1].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[2].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[3].",filter)";
        }
        elseif($checksize == 5)
        {
            $new = "FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[0].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[1].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[2].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[3].",filter) AND FIND_IN_SET (".$newbreak[5].",filter) ";
        }else
        {

        }
$query =
 sprintf("SELECT * ,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM userdata WHERE 
$new HAVING distance < '%s'   ORDER BY distance",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Comment: Pretty much just a less flexible version of my suggestion. Note that FIND_IN_SET is a string function and the first parameter is meant to be a string.